# Bootstrap 3 Navbar not collapsing at custom breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have customized bootstrap with [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62e0d59451c57daa1cf9) config. I have set

```
"@grid-float-breakpoint": "810px",
"@grid-float-breakpoint-max": "800px"
```

However the navbar does not seem to collapse at 800px or anything close to that. The navbar collapses at about 600-650px. What am I doing wrong. Do I have to change any other values as well?

Navbar

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-selected="#new-li">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
            </span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/C5.WebApp/Content/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="inbox-li"><a href="/C5.WebApp/">Posteingang</a></li>
            <li id="tasks-li"><a href="/C5.WebApp/Tasks">Aufgaben</a></li>
            <li id="calendar-li"><a href="/C5.WebApp/Calendar">Kalender</a></li>
            <li id="contacts-li"><a href="/C5.WebApp/Contacts">Kontakte</a></li>
            <li class="active" id="new-li"><a href="/C5.WebApp/Activity/Create">Neue Aktivität</a></li>
            <li><a href="/C5.WebApp/Login/Logout">Abmelden</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the same variables as you, and it worked correctly for me. I think you will need to provide more detail. In the browser, inspect the `.navbar-toggle` button and see what the min-width of the media query is set to.

Comment: @Schmalzy I did not manage to find min-width property of the toogle

Answer (score 0):

Check your `bootstrap.css` file (non-minified), starting on line 3911 you should see the following code... Make sure the `min-width: 810px`  is correct.

```
@media (min-width: 810px)
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

If this is correct, then you either have some custom CSS overwriting the break-point or you do not have the correct CSS file linked in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your problem is caused by using the `<div class="container">` instead of the `<div class="container-fluid">` inside your `<nav>`.

In the default situation where the breakpoint is set to 768px (equal to the max size of the xs grid) the problem do not happens due to the `.container` class do not have a fixed width for screen widths below the 768px (the grid is fluid). Above the 768 the `.container` class set the width to 750px;. For your new breakpoint around the 800px this fixed width of the `.container` class in the sm grid will cause your problem. The `container-fluid` class do not set a fixed width.

Comment: Changed the container to fluid, does not work either